# Integration issue visjs in MicroStrategy

Tags: vis.js, microstrategy

I am trying to integrate vis.js in Micro Strategy.

Using the visualisation builder :

- Added the visjs library
- Added a simple piece of code creating a vis dataset.

`var items = new vis.Dataset([...])`

Using the browsers debugger I get "message: vis is not defined"

I did do a similar small test with d3 without any issue.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: That would suggest the library is not imported correctly. The "similar small test" with d3 was `d3+viz.js` or was it `d3+Micro Strategy`?  If you haven't solved yet, I would suggest starting with a simple `vis.js` only page to ensure the import is working.